# How to Merge Objects Of Varying Properties And Lengths Without Duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I am attempting to merge two objects that both, have some same keys/associated arrays and different keys. The associated arrays are also of different length. To give you a better picture, I have included some code below that shows the two objects I am trying to merge (filters1 and filters2) and the desired outcome after merging (combinedFilters1).

I've tried methods like Object.assign() or for loops (which I have also included below), but I can't seem to get the result I outlined below (combinedFilters1). Any suggestions? All help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
// first object
this.filters1 = {
      "categories":
      [
        {
          "categoryName":"Video",
          "categoryAttributes":
          [
            {
              "name":"aspectRatio",
              "values":["4:3", "16:15"]
            },
            {
              "name":"Bit Rate",
              "values":["256kbps", "512kbps"]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "categoryName":"Audio",
          "categoryAttributes":
          [
            {
              "name":"Speaker",
              "values":["In-built", "External Connector"]
            },
            {
              "name":"Bit Rate",
              "values":["256kbps", "376kbps", "512kbps"]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };

// second object
this.filters2 = {
  "categories":
  [
    {
      "categoryName":"Video",
      "categoryAttributes":
      [
        {
          "name":"aspectRatio",
          "values":["4:3", "16:15", "16:9"]
        },
        {
          "name":"Bit Rate",
          "values":["256kbps", "512kbps", "1024kbps"]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "categoryName":"Audio",
      "categoryAttributes":
      [
        {
          "name":"Speaker",
          "values":["In-built", "External Connector"]
        },
        {
          "name":"Bit Rate",
          "values":["256kbps", "376kbps", "512kbps", "1024kbps"]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "categoryName":"OS",
      "categoryAttributes":
      [
        {
          "name":"Android",
          "values":["Lolipop", "Marshmello"]
        },
        {
          "name":"Apple",
          "values":["IOS 5", "IOS 6"]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

// desired outcome
this.combinedFilters1 = {
  "categories":
  [
    {
      "categoryName":"Video",
      "categoryAttributes":
      [
        {
          "name":"aspectRatio",
          "values":["4:3", "16:15", "16:9"]
        },
        {
          "name":"Bit Rate",
          "values":["256kbps", "512kbps", "1024kbps"]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "categoryName":"Audio",
      "categoryAttributes":
      [
        {
          "name":"Speaker",
          "values":["In-built", "External Connector"]
        },
        {
          "name":"Bit Rate",
          "values":["256kbps", "376kbps", "512kbps", "1024kbps"]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "categoryName":"OS",
      "categoryAttributes":
      [
        {
          "name":"Android",
          "values":["Lolipop", "Marshmello"]
        },
        {
          "name":"Apple",
          "values":["IOS 5", "IOS 6"]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

// attempted this loop
for (let i = 0, j = 0; i < this.filters1.categories.length,
      j < this.filters2.categories.length; i++, j++) {
      // console.log(this.filters1.categories[i].categoryName + " " + this.filters2.categories[j].categoryName);

  if(this.filters1.categories.includes(this.filters2.categories[j].categoryName)) {
    continue;
  } else {
    this.combinedFilters1.categories.push({"categoryName": this.filters2.categories[j].categoryName});
  }

  console.log(this.combinedFilters1);

  for (let k = 0, l = 0; k < this.filters1.categories[i].categoryAttributes.length,
    l < this.filters2.categories[j].categoryAttributes.length; k++, l++) {
    console.log(this.filters1.categories[i].categoryAttributes[k]);
    console.log(this.filters2.categories[j].categoryAttributes[l]);

    if(this.filters1.categories.includes({"categoryAttributes" : [{"name": this.filters2.categories[j].categoryAttributes[l].name}]})) {
      continue;
    } else {
      this.combinedFilters1.categories[i]["categoryAttributes"] = [{"name": this.filters2.categories[j].categoryAttributes[l].name}];
    }
  }
}
```

The first part of the for loop adds the unique categories (video, audio, OS), but the second part of the for loop doesn't add the unique attributes and I need to do the same for the values array. All help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a dynamic function which takes two arrays, and array of entries with key and value names, a function processing the final level and an index.

```js
function merge(a, b, entries, final, index = 0) {
    var [k, v] = entries[index];
    return b.reduce((r, o) => {
        var temp = r.find(q => o[k] === q[k]);
        if (!temp) {
            r.push(o);
        } else if (index + 1 === entries.length) {
            temp[v] = final(temp[v], o[v]);
        } else {
            merge(temp[v], o[v], entries, final, index + 1);
        }                
        return r;
    }, a);
}

var filters1 = { categories: [{ categoryName: "Video", categoryAttributes: [{ name: "aspectRatio", values: ["4:3", "16:15"] }, { name: "Bit Rate", values: ["256kbps", "512kbps"] }] }, { categoryName: "Audio", categoryAttributes: [{ name: "Speaker", values: ["In-built", "External Connector"] }, { name: "Bit Rate", values: ["256kbps", "376kbps", "512kbps"] }] }] },
    filters2 = { categories: [{ categoryName: "Video", categoryAttributes: [{ name: "aspectRatio", values: ["4:3", "16:15", "16:9"] }, { name: "Bit Rate", values: ["256kbps", "512kbps", "1024kbps"] }] }, { categoryName: "Audio", categoryAttributes: [{ name: "Speaker", values: ["In-built", "External Connector"] }, { name: "Bit Rate", values: ["256kbps", "376kbps", "512kbps", "1024kbps"] }] }, { categoryName: "OS", categoryAttributes: [{ name: "Android", values: ["Lolipop", "Marshmello"] }, { name: "Apple", values: ["IOS 5", "IOS 6"] }] }] },
    parts = [
        [undefined, 'categories'],
        ['categoryName', 'categoryAttributes'],
        ['name', 'values']
    ],
    fn = (a, b) => [...new Set([...a, ...b])],
    result = merge([filters1], [filters2], parts, fn);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is perfect, you're a life saver, thank you! I used it in 2 iterations because I had to merge a third object.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to combine the two arrays into one:

```
this.combinedFilters1 = {categories: [...this.filters1.categories, ...this.filters2.categories]}
```

But in your 'desired outcome' section, it looks like you're overwriting any array elements of `filters1` that have the same `categoryName` as the elements of `filters2`. If that's what you're trying to do first I'd structure your data so that categories is an object rather than an array, like so

```
this.filters1 = {
"categories": {
  "Video": {
    "categoryAttributes": [
        {
          "name":"aspectRatio",
          "values":["4:3", "16:15"]
        },
        {
          "name":"Bit Rate",
          "values":["256kbps", "512kbps"]
        }
      ]
    },
    "Audio": {/*data here*/}
  }
}
```

then do

```
this.combinedFilters1 = {categories: {...this.filters1.categories, ...this.filters2.categories}}
```

That will give you the behavior of the second overwriting the first.

If you really can't change the data structure, then you'll have to do some inefficient looping.

```
this.combinedFilters1 = {...this.filters1};
for (const cat1 of this.combinedFilters1.categories) {
  this.combinedFilters1.categories = this.filters2.categories.reduce((accumulator, cat2) => {
    accumulator.push(cat1.categoryName === cat2.categoryName ? cat2 : cat1)
    return accumulator;
  }, [])
}
```

Note: this code only works if `filters2` is longer than `filters1`;

Comment: I cannot change the structure of the original objects. I tried the loop you provided, but it gives the following output:

Comment: `{"categories":[{"categoryName":"Audio","categoryAttributes":[{"name":"Speaker","values":["In-built","External Connector"]},{"name":"Bit Rate","values":["256kbps","376kbps","512kbps"]}]},{"categoryName":"Audio","categoryAttributes":[{"name":"Speaker","values":["In-built","External Connector"]},{"name":"Bit Rate","values":["256kbps","376kbps","512kbps","1024kbps"]}]},{"categoryName":"Audio","categoryAttributes":[{"name":"Speaker","values":["In-built","External Connector"]},{"name":"Bit Rate","values":["256kbps","376kbps","512kbps"]}]}]}`